# Modelling imbalanced dataset using random forest and neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, random-forest

I am trying to develop a model with imbalanced data for prediction of positive class. I am using neural network and random forest separately. The issue in both the algorithm is that the model performance drops significantly in the out of time sample. In the dev sample, both approaches are yielding good results. In random forest, the OOB score is similar to Out of time score, but yet the classification is not accurate in the sense that in the out of time sample the random forest model is able to identify only 2% of positive labels whereas in the development sample it is identifying more than 90%. Similar story in neural network where the model is able to identify around 70% of positive labels in development sample, but is failing miserably in out of time. Any suggestion on this will help. I am using optuna to fine tune the hyper-parameters

Comment: I would recommend using a precision-recall curve to judge your imbalanced models: https://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/08/19/NLP_Metrics/#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20an%20imbalanced,scenario%20as%20a%20ROC%20curve.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple case of models that are overfitting.

There are a variety of things you could try to see if it makes any difference:

1. For the random forest, limit the depth. This reduces the complexity each tree can learn.
2. For the NN, reduce the number of hidden layers if you have a lot of them, and reduce the number of nodes in the hidden layers.
3. For the NN, you should implement early stopping. This will require you to define a validation set to compare performance against. You should stop training your model once the training performance and validation performance start to deviate (validation performance will suffer as the model starts to overfit.

It is very likely that in all these cases you training-set performance will decrease, and the testing set performance should increase. They will balance out at some level.

After this, you might see that the class imbalance becomes the new limiting factor. You could try getting more data, or artificially balancing the data using some sort of sampling strategy, or generating synthetic data for the smaller class. There are pros and cons for these choices.